# Setting up JFrame with leftPanel, topPanel and bottomPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

First time posting here, and let me first say that I'm a bit of a Java noob, I've only started learning it in uni this year.

So anyway, I have to create a UI for a Tamagotchi project, and I'm trying to create it using JFrame etc.

This is what I'm trying to create: [image]

This is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DogUI {

    private JFrame DogUI;
    private JPanel leftPanel, topPanel, bottomPanel, rightPanels;
    private JButton jb;
    private JLabel lb, lb1, lb2;

    public DogUI() {
        GUI();
    }

    public void GUI() {

        DogUI = new JFrame("Dog UI");
        DogUI.setSize(800, 600);
        DogUI.setResizable(false);

        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

        rightPanels = new JPanel();
        rightPanels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanels, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        DogUI.setVisible(true);

        lb = new JLabel("Name: ");
        leftPanel.add(lb);

        lb1 = new JLabel("Image");
        topPanel.add(lb1);

        lb2 = new JLabel("Buttons");
        bottomPanel.add(lb2);

        rightPanels.add(topPanel);
        rightPanels.add(bottomPanel);

        DogUI.add(rightPanels);

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new DogUI();
    }
}
```

This is what I end up with: [image]

I'm sure it's something simple, or perhaps I am going the complete wrong way about doing it, but please try explain it in layman's terms if possible.

Thanks.
Chris.

Comment: Please have a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You will find a lot of sample there.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a good look through all of those different layouts, and hopefully I get the one I want to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a GridLayout instead.

```
public void GUI() {
    DogUI = new JFrame("Dog UI");
    DogUI.setSize(800, 600);
    DogUI.setResizable(false);
    DogUI.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));//1row 2col

    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

    topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

    bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

    rightPanels = new JPanel();
    rightPanels.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));//2row 1col

    lb = new JLabel("Name: ");
    leftPanel.add(lb);

    lb1 = new JLabel("Image");
    topPanel.add(lb1);

    lb2 = new JLabel("Buttons");
    bottomPanel.add(lb2);

    rightPanels.add(topPanel);
    rightPanels.add(bottomPanel);

    DogUI.add(leftPanel);
    DogUI.add(rightPanels);

    DogUI.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly, no doubt what others had suggested was the same way you did it, but I made the changes to my code and it worked. Thank you again!

Comment: @candrews13, certainly.  Also, if you noticed, I moved the location of `DogUI.setVisible(true);`.  Though I don't remember exactly what the reason was, I do remember from my swing days that you should really only display something after it's done being built.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are only adding the `rightPanels` to the frame, you never add `leftPanel`
2. The `rightPanel` is using `X_AXIS` which is horizontal. You want `Y_AXIS`
3. When you *do* add the `leftPanel`, you're going to want to set your frame's layout to `GridLayout(1, 2)`. See [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)
4. `setVisible` *after* adding all your components.
5. Follow Java namingConvention. variables begin with lower case, using camel casing. `DogUI` → `dogUI`
6. Swing apps should be run from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You can do this by wrapping the code in the `main` in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a parent JPanel with a BorderLayout. That parent JPanel contains two other panels, on the east and west side of it. The west side can contain your progress panel, and the east side contains another JPanel, which has a GridLayout of 1 column and 2 rows, or alternatively, a BorderLayout. From there you can add the other two JPanels to that last JPanel which represent whatever that right hand side of the picture shows.

The overall parent JPanel could also be a GridLayout with 2 columns and 1 row, but a BorderLayout might look better as you might find one side of the application might not need as much space and might limit how much space it takes up. Perhaps the east panel should be a BorderLayout too as your image might not take up that much space on the north side giving the components on the south side the rest of the container's available space.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! As Braj pointed me in the direction of different layout managers like yourself, I noticed in Braj's link the GridLayout, I'll have a good look at those and choose one and have a go.